# SELECT data based on result of previous row in table

Tags: mysql, select

I have a database of students.

```
    CREATE TABLE classlist
        (`id` int, `studentid` int, `subjectid` int, `presentid` int)
    ;

    CREATE TABLE student
        (`id` int, `name` varchar(4))
    ;

    CREATE TABLE subject
        (`id` int, `name` varchar(4))
    ;

    CREATE TABLE classStatus
        (`id` int, `name` varchar(8))
    ;

    INSERT INTO classlist
        (`id`, `studentid`, `subjectid`, `presentid`)
    VALUES
        (1, 111, 1, 1),
        (2, 222, 3, 0),
        (3, 333, 2, 1),
        (4, 111, 4, 1),
        (5, 111, 1, 0),
        (6, 222, 3, 0),
        (7, 333, 2, 1),
        (8, 111, 4, 1),
        (9, 111, 2, 0),
        (10, 111, 4, 1),
        (11, 111, 1, 1),
        (12, 333, 3, 1),
        (13, 333, 2, 1),
        (14, 333, 3, 1)
    ;

    INSERT INTO student
        (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES
    (111, 'John'),
    (222, 'Kate'),
    (333, 'Matt')
    ;

    INSERT INTO subject
        (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES
    (1, 'MATH'),
    (2, 'ENG'),
    (3, 'SCI'),
    (4, 'GEO')
    ;

    INSERT INTO classStatus
        (`id`, `name`)
    VALUES
    (0, 'Absent'),
    (1, 'Present')
    ;
```

And I have a query which shows how many times they have been present or absent.

```
    SELECT
       studentid,
       students.name AS NAME,
       SUM(presentid = 1) AS present,
       SUM(presentid = 0) AS absent

    FROM classlist
    INNER JOIN student as students ON classlist.studentid=students.id

     GROUP BY studentid, NAME
```

See this fiddle below.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fe0b0/1

There seems to be a trend from looking at this sample data that after someone attends subjectid 4 they are often not coming to the next class. How can I capture this in a query.   I want to ONLY show data WHERE last subjectid =4. So in my sample data rows matching my criteria would be.

```
    (5, 111, 1, 0),
    (9, 111, 2, 0),
    (11, 111, 1, 1),
```

as these rows are all the next row of a studentid who had a subjectid=4.

My output would be

```
    | STUDENTID | NAME | PRESENT    | ABSENT|
    | 111       | John | 1          | 2     |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the next class for a student, use a correlated subquery:

```
select cl.*,
       (select min(cl2.id) from classlist cl2 where cl2.studentid = cl.studentid and cl2.id > cl.id) as nextcl
from classlist cl
```

Plugging this into your query example tell you you who is present and absent for the next class:

```
SELECT students.id, students.name AS NAME,
       SUM(cl.presentid = 1) AS present, SUM(cl.presentid = 0) AS absent,
       sum(clnext.presentid = 1) as presentnext
FROM (select cl.*,
             (select min(cl2.id) from classlist cl2 where cl2.studentid = cl.studentid and cl2.id > cl.id) as nextcl
      from classlist cl
     ) cl INNER JOIN
     student as students
     ON cl.studentid = students.id left outer join
     classlist clnext
     on cl.nextcl = clnext.id
 GROUP BY students.id, students.NAME
```

Add a `where cl.subjectid = 4` to get the answer for subject 4.

I fixed the query.  The SQLFiddle is [k](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c59d3/4/0).

Comment: Thanks, I got a number of errors when I put this into sqlfiddle, I wasn't sure if they were just syntax errors? Unknown column 'cl2id' in 'field list' I presume this needed to be changed to cl2.id?
Unknown column 'cl1.studentid' in 'where clause' I wasn't sure where cl1 was coming from?  So I changed this to cl?
Unknown column 'students.studentid' in 'field list': I couldn't work out why this was happening?

Comment: Undoubtedly SQL Fiddle.  If you set this up in SQL Fiddle, it is a good idea to include a link to it.  One problem was `cl2id` in the subquery rather than `cl2.id`, for instance.

Comment: I updated the syntax errors so it now works when you plug it in to SQL Fiddle. I also added in absentnext so you can see when they were absent next.  Thanks for your great help!

Comment: Prpbably best to leave it as unaccepted until the edits i made to the answer get peer reviewed to stop confusion from other users

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty solution could be to get the Classlist.Id for all lines where subjectid=4 (let's call them n) then select all the lines where Id = n+1